# luaotfload: how to use font in current directory?

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

I'd like to use a font in the current directory with luaotfload. I tried to generate the database:

```
OSFONTDIR=$PWD mkluatexfontdb
```

but this gives me endless output of:

```
$ OSFONTDIR=$PWD mkluatexfontdb

luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
luaotfload | Font names database not found, generating new one.
             This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
luaotfload | Font names database not found, generating new one.
             This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
...
```

What can I do do to use a (OTF) font in the current directory with luaotfload?

Comment: looks like a problem with `luaotfload`, please report at https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaotfload/issues

Comment: also, `luaotfload` allows specifying fonts by file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OSFONTDIR` variable is, I think, not intended to be used like this.

Here's an example using both plain and LaTeX font loading (luaotfload.sty can be `\input` in plain TeX if you're not using LaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\font\1="file:MyriadPro-BlackCond.otf" at 12pt\1 hello
\normalfont normal font
\fontspec{MyriadPro-BlackCond.otf}
hello again
\end{document}
```

For the fontspec example, it auto-detects that it's a font from the filesystem by the existence of `.otf` at the end of the name. If this doesn't work for you, I think we'll need to do more debugging in another forum (the [lualatex-dev](http://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/lualatex-dev) mailing list would be a good idea).

Comment: No, it does not work (the plain TeX variant): `Font \jss=file:JosefinSansStd-Light.otf at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.` The LaTeX variant does not give me an error message but does not switch to the font either.

Comment: With `\fontspec[Path=/my/current/dir]{...}` I get the same metric data not found-error.

Comment: @Patrick — seems like a problem somewhere. Not sure if we can resolve this here. (I've edited my answer above.)

Comment: I will investigate further and see what I can do to track down the problem.

Comment: it works now. Thanks (also to @Khaled Hosny)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\directlua{fonts.names.scan(".")}
\font\test={name:Gota Light} % whatever the font is
\test test
\bye
```

But it does not work now because of a long undiscovered bug (you can fix it by replacing `"zapfino"` with `dir` in the file `otfl-font-nms.lua`.)

Fontspec's `ExternalLocation` would be extended to use this feature.

Comment: A fixed version have been uploaded to CTAN and is available in texlive now.